# LATEX : Placing chart on the right of the text (enumerate)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new here, just learning latex and tikz package. I am trying to put tikz picture on the right of the text but have problem with that. I tried 
**minipages**,**adjustbox** and few more and can't do it. Maybe someone can help me? Thanks in advance.
I need smth like that:
[image: Draw]

**My code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\geometry{lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]

\item  
Na rysunku obok przedstawiony jest fragment wykresu funkcji wielomianowej         
$y=W(x)$, gdzie st.$W(x)=3$.
Funkcja \textit W ma dwa miejsca zerowe: $\dfrac{1}{2}$ i $2$. 
\newline
Do wykresu funkcji $W$ należy punkt $A = \left(1\dfrac{1}{2}, 2 \right)$.
\newline
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item Napisz wzór funkcji $W$ w postaci ogólnej.
\item Oblicz resztę z dzielenia wielomianu $W(x)$ przez wielomian                   
$P(x)=4x^2-8x+3$.
\end{enumerate}


\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle     
45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]\raggedright
\draw [color=cqcqcq,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt, xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.5cm] 
(-1.2,-1.2) grid (4.2,2.7);
 \draw[->,color=black] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[above] {$x$};
\foreach \x in {0.5,1,2}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]     
{\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0,-1.5) -- (0,2.5) node[right] {$y$};
\foreach \y in {-1,1,2}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left]     
 {\footnotesize $\y$};
\clip(-2,-1.5) rectangle (4,2.5);
\draw[line width=0.8pt,color=qqwuqq, smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.0:4.0]     
plot(\x,{0-4*(\x)^3+12*(\x)^2-9*(\x)+2});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (2.1,-1) node[right] {$y=W(x)$};
\fill [color=qqwuqq] (1.5,2) circle (2.0pt);
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (1.81,2.15) node[right] {$A = \left(1\dfrac{1}{2}, 2     
\right)$};
\end{scriptsize}
\path [fill=blue] (current bounding box.north) ++(20,-\baselineskip)     
 coordinate (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually rely on `wrapfigure` to do this, but [you can't use `wrapfigure` in `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232110/141337), so I used `minipage` instead:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]

\item  
Na rysunku obok przedstawiony jest fragment wykresu funkcji wielomianowej         
$y=W(x)$, gdzie st.$W(x)=3$.
Funkcja \textit W ma dwa miejsca zerowe: $\dfrac{1}{2}$ i $2$. 
\newline
Do wykresu funkcji $W$ należy punkt $A = \left(1\dfrac{1}{2}, 2 \right)$.
\newline

\begin{minipage}{.60\textwidth}
  \begin{enumerate}[a)]
  \item Napisz wzór funkcji $W$ w postaci ogólnej.
  \item Oblicz resztę z dzielenia wielomianu $W(x)$ przez wielomian                   
  $P(x)=4x^2-8x+3$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.30\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle     
  45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]\raggedright
  \draw [color=cqcqcq,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt, xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.5cm] 
  (-1.2,-1.2) grid (4.2,2.7);
   \draw[->,color=black] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[above] {$x$};
  \foreach \x in {0.5,1,2}
  \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]     
  {\footnotesize $\x$};
  \draw[->,color=black] (0,-1.5) -- (0,2.5) node[right] {$y$};
  \foreach \y in {-1,1,2}
  \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left]     
   {\footnotesize $\y$};
  \clip(-2,-1.5) rectangle (4,2.5);
  \draw[line width=0.8pt,color=qqwuqq, smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.0:4.0]     
  plot(\x,{0-4*(\x)^3+12*(\x)^2-9*(\x)+2});
  \begin{scriptsize}
  \draw[color=qqwuqq] (2.1,-1) node[right] {$y=W(x)$};
  \fill [color=qqwuqq] (1.5,2) circle (2.0pt);
  \draw[color=qqwuqq] (1.81,2.15) node[right] {$A = \left(1\dfrac{1}{2}, 2     
  \right)$};
  \end{scriptsize}
  \path [fill=blue] (current bounding box.north) ++(20,-\baselineskip)     
   coordinate (c);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]